# Adding hover effect when hovering on something else

Tags: css

I have a nav-bar with an `<a>` and inside the `<a>` I have I want to make the icon translate when I hover on the a text. Here is the code.

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="button">
        <a href="index.html"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt icon"></i> Go back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far I tried this:

```css
.button:hover ~ i {
    transform: translateX(-3px);
}
```

Comment: `~` is the sibling selector and your `<i>` isn't a sibling of `.button`. It's a descendant

Answer (score 0):

The link is child of the `.button` div and the `i` is a child of that so:

```
.button:hover a i {
transform: translateX(-3px);
}
```

```css
.button:hover a i {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
  /* wildly exaggerated */
  display: inline-block;
  /* required to transform inline elements */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="nav-bar">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="index.html"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt icon"></i> Go back</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank , Kinda works , I have a transform: trnaslatex(180 deg) on the icon , and now is translateing the icon but also flips it back 180 deg :D

Comment: You can't have translate *twice*. Do you mean `rotate`?

Comment: yes , my bad . this is the code .icon {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}


.button:hover a i {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
    display: inline-block;

}

Comment: then merge the two transforms: `transform: rotateY(180deg) translatex(-3px)` on hover.

Comment: got it, Thanks !